# percentage related task

Tags: algebra-precalculus

this question is related  to finding proportion of alcohol in  Solution.suppose that from dishes,where was $80$% of alcohol,they  Poured  in 1 liter pure water,then  Poured out   $3$ liter solution,after that they again poured in  $1$ liter pure water ,after which they  got  solution with  $50$% alcohol,question is to find what was a amount of  alcohol   from the beginning.

my approaches is following,suppose that from the beginning total amount of solution was $x$,which means that $0.8$ was  with alcohol and $0.2$ was pure water,after they poured $1$  liter pure water,total amount  solution  was  $x+1$ and pure water would be  $1.2$,after that
they poured out $3$ liter  solution,so my question is what is a  amount of  percentage  of alcohol in $3$ liter?for instance suppose that we have    $10$ liter solution,which means that  $8$ liter is alcohol and  $2$ liter is pure water,if they will  pour out $3$ liter,it means that we have  such kind of proportion

```
$10$   $8$

$3       x$
```

which means   $x=3*8/10=2.4$,so in our case it would be $3*0.8=2.4%$?
so i think  we  will have following information for solve this problem

beginning  $x$ liter,with $.8*x$ alcohol and $0.2$ pure water

after pour in $1$ liter, $x+1$ in total,with $0.8*x/(x+1)$ with alcohol and $1.2$ pure water.
after  pour out $3$ liter solution,what it should be? $3*0.8*x/(x+1)$ ?total amount would be $x-2$,please help me

Comment: If there is 80% of alcohol in $x$ amount of solute, how much alcohol is there? Same question for water.

Comment: $0.8*x$ for alcohol, for water $0.2*x$ it is right yes?i think  she  misses  $x$ in front of each percentage

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there.

Step 1. Let's start with $x$ litres in the dish, of which $0.8x$ is alcohol and $0.2x$ is pure water.

Step 2. Now add 1 litre of pure water. Total volume is $x+1$ litres, of which $0.8x$ is alcohol, and $(1+0.2x)$ is water. The proportions of alcohol and water are now $\frac{0.8x}{1+x}$ and $\frac{1+0.2x}{1+x}$.

Step 3. Next pour out 3 litres of water.Total volume is $x+1-3=x-2$ litres, of which $\frac{0.8x(x-2)}{(1+x)}$ is alcohol and $\frac{(1+0.2x)(x-2)}{(1+x)}$ is water.

This answers your question about the percentage of alcohol in $x-2$ litres. Try this out with $x=10$ litres as you did above.

Can you see how to proceed to the final answer? Step 4 will add 1 litre of water, making the alcohol: water ratio 50:50.

Comment: then they again poured  in $1$ liter pure  water,so it means that  total liter is $x-1$,pure water is $2+0.2*x$,so  our  final answer would be that  $0.5*(x-1)=0.8*x/(1+x)$?

Comment: why it is  $0.8*x(x-2)/(x+1)$?

Comment: @dato. I thought we should leave something for the OP to work on to get to the final solution.

Comment: i am also interested  in solution of this

Comment: @dato. I've edited my response so that we can reference the steps in my approach. In Step 3 we calculate the alcohol:water ratio in $x-2$ litres of fluid.

Comment: generally i have question,if  $x$  liter contains $80$  alcohol,then how much is in $n$ liter,where $n<x$?

Comment: @dato. I've edited my response so that we can reference the steps in my approach. In Step 3 we calculate the litres of alcohol and the litres of water making up $x-2$ litres of total fluid. The RATIO of alcohol to water in Step3 is therefore $\frac{0.8x}{1+0.2x}$. In Step 4, as you point out, we will now have $x-1$ litres. We use the alcohol:water ratio in Step 3 to calculate the amount of alcohol in $x-1$ litres of fluid in Step 4. But we are told this ratio is $50\%$. So we get a solvable quadratic equation in $x$.